# Java - let user write own code, then compile it, then use it within same runtime

Tags: java, compilation, on-the-fly

I need to perform following steps:

1. Let user write own code - no problem, it's just one interface to implement and I save a file
2. Compile it - no problem, I used `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()` and created **.class** file
3. Let user use this new code - **here I am stuck**. I have .class file and now what? I need somehow add it in my project and I don't know how.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you familiar with class loaders?

Comment: Aside question: do you filter the code like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /");`

Comment: yipes - this would not be any software allowed on any system i work with.,, :)

Comment: @Randy: Depends on who the "user" is.  If it's going to be used by developers with shell access already, it's no additional risk.  If it's going to take data from over the web, it's a cannonball-sized security hole.  Unless Runtime is able to execute with higher privs than the user running the initial app, which I don't think it does.

Comment: "user" is programmer in this case :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`URLClassLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to load the classes. Then you can use reflection to instantiate and manipulate them.

Comment: A small addition: If you don't want to save the generated class files to some file, you can either give a suitable URLStreamHandlerFactory to your URLClassLoader (to read from your in-memory class files instead), or simplier use an own ClassLoader implementation with overridden `findClass()`.

Comment: Cool this works :) Luckily it wasn't too hard. @Paulo: thanks, but I actually need files :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is write your own ClassLoader that will load the classes you have just compiled.
There are many examples on the web on how to do that.

Here is one to load from the web: http://kazi-masudul-alam.blogspot.com/2008/01/java-classloader.html

Comment: Reflection is not "another option", but simply needed in addition to the classloader to invoke methods from those classes (or at least create an initial object).